# Complte event for Editor behaving like Unfocussed event

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, editor

I am trying for saving some value in the editor after clicking on done on the keyboard for that I used the `Completed` event for the editor but this is calling while tapping on everywhere in the view like the `Unfocused` event. How to avoid that this?

```
<controls:CustomEditor Keyboard="Default" 
                       ReturnKeyType="Next" 
                       TextChanged="Comment_Changed" 
                       Completed="OnDoneClicked"  
                       VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                       Text="{Binding QuestionComment}">
    <controls:CustomEditor.FontSize>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <OnIdiom.Phone>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" 
                            iOS="12" 
                            Android="12" 
                            WinPhone="30" />
            </OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" 
                            iOS="13" 
                            Android="13" 
                            WinPhone="40" />
            </OnIdiom.Tablet>
        </OnIdiom>
    </controls:CustomEditor.FontSize>
</controls:CustomEditor>
```

CustomEditorClass is as following:

```
public const string ReturnKeyPropertyName = "ReturnKeyType";

public CustomEditor() { }

public static readonly BindableProperty ReturnKeyTypeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: ReturnKeyPropertyName,
    returnType: typeof(ReturnKeyTypes),
    declaringType: typeof(CustomEditor),
    defaultValue: ReturnKeyTypes.Done );

public ReturnKeyTypes ReturnKeyType
{
    get { return (ReturnKeyTypes)GetValue(ReturnKeyTypeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ReturnKeyTypeProperty, value); }
}

public enum ReturnKeyTypes : int
{
    Default,
    Go,
    Google,
    Join,
    Next,
    Route,
    Search,
    Send,
    Yahoo,
    Done,
    EmergencyCall,
    Continue
}
```

And the event is as following:

```
private async void OnDoneClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //some logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.Editor.Completed/), this is the intended behavior

> iOS (Unfocusing the editor or pressing "Done" triggers the event). Android / Windows Phone (Unfocusing the Editor triggers the event)

I've checked some messenger apps (iOS) and they don't have a `done` button on the keyboard at all, they provide a send button besides the entry control.

Depending on what you try to achieve, I'd ditch the `done` button on the keyboard altogether and rely on some sort of view on the UI, that is used for that purpose. This is platform dependent behavior anyway, Android does not support it at all, AFAIK. In order to get rid of the done button, you'll have to implement a custom renderer and set the `InputAccessoryView` of the native control to `null` (see [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88141/remove-done-button-over-keyboard-in-xamarin-forms))

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEditor), typeof(CustomEditorRenderer))]
namespace ProjectName.iOS
{
    public class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            this.Control.InputAccessoryView = null;
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want a button to send, you could create a derivative of `Editor` with a custom renderer, that creates a `InputAccessoryView` and raises an `SendPressed` event on your custom `Editor` when the `InputAccessoryView` is pressed. But remember, this is *not* possible for Android.